# R packages for mortality models ( Siler, Mixture)

Tags: r

I am using the Rstudio to run mortality models. I have to make graphs of Gompertz, siler, gamma Gompertz, extreme value and mixture models. But i am not able to make the graphs. specially for siler model.
https://eehh-stanford.github.io/yada/articles/siler.html
from this link, i installed YADA package, but the package don't have the command of "hazsiler, hsiler" in it. kindly guide me to solve it.

Comment: See [ask]. You said you haven't been able to make your charts, but haven't said anything about what that means or why that is.

Comment: It looks like these functions were removed from the package quite a while ago. https://github.com/eehh-stanford/yada/commit/26715fddca85d380113c35d1f0a580aa5c4bd232 . You might have to try a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=siler+mortality+model+R) and/or contact the maintainers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.